# Codeigniter: How to paginate search results

Tags: codeigniter, search, pagination

When I search a keyword it just show me all the like in the database. Then if I click the next in the pagination. The keyword is lost. How do i maintain the searched keyword if i click the next button in pagination?

Controller:

```
public function info($offset=0)
{       
$filter = $this->input->get("filter");
    $limit = 5;
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $filter = $this->input->get("filter");


    $this->db->where('is_valid','1');
    $this->db->like('requested_by',$filter);
    $search = $this->input->get("search");
      $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $config["base_url"] = "/ticketing/index.php/ticketing/info/";

    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('db_ticketing.tr_ticket');
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
//  $config['base_url'] = ("/ticketing/index.php/ticketing/info/");
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = false;
    $config['num_links'] = 4;


    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();



$data['ticket_list'] = $this->ticketing_mdl->get_all_ticket( $limit, $offset);



    $this->load->view('ticketing/header');
    $this->load->view('ticketing/left_menu');
    $this->load->view('ticketing/info',$data);
}
```

Model

```
function get_all_ticket($limit,$offset)
{
    if($this->input->get('search')){
     $match = $this->input->get('search');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_ticketing.tr_ticket WHERE requested_by LIKE '%$match%' limit $limit offset  $offset";
        return $this->db->query($sql);

    }
}
```

View:

```
<form method="get" action="">
                <tr>
                    <td>Search:</td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="search" /></td>

                </tr>
                </form>
```

Comment: you can use session or uri segment for searching next page in ci.

Comment: tried the uri segment but don't know how to properly implement it.

Comment: you will get $this->uri->segment(); store in a variable and then use the variable for searching next page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$count = $this->ticketing_mdl->count_all_ticket(); # get total count matched
//product pagination
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . '/ticketing/index.php/info/';
$config['total_rows'] = $count;
$config['per_page'] = 5;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$limit = $config['per_page'];

//Bootstrap pagination style
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$data['ticket_list'] = $this->ticketing_mdl->get_all_ticket($limit,$page);

$this->load->view('ticketing/header');
$this->load->view('ticketing/left_menu');
$this->load->view('ticketing/info',$data);
```

**In model **

```
# get count of record
function count_all_ticket()
{
    if($this->input->get('search')){
        $match = $this->input->get('search');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_ticketing.tr_ticket WHERE requested_by LIKE '%$match%'";
        $query =  $this->db->query($sql);
        $result = $query->result_array();

        $count = count($result);
        return $count;

    }
}

# get all results matched
function get_all_ticket($limit,$page)
{
    if($this->input->get('search'))
    {
        $match = $this->input->get('search');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_ticketing.tr_ticket WHERE requested_by LIKE '%$match%'  LIMIT $page, $limit";
        $query =  $this->db->query($sql);
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: the pagination is not working properly. and also 
i got this error (Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function result() on array)

Comment: still having the same problem when i click on a paginate link the url reset then the search keyword is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.
I've solved in this way:

- I got my search keywords from search form through post method to functionOne().
- I just created a session with the keywords then redirected to another
  function say functionTwo().
- In the newly created function i.e. functionTwo(), I fetched keywords from the session and wrote the CodeIgniter pagination code.
- In the 'base_url' of pagination code, I used functionTwo().